# Does this gear mesh pattern look good?

Tags: jeep, gears

[image]
[image]

2017 Jeep Wrangler JK Unlimited Sport S.

Factory:

- 3.21 open diff

New:

- ARB Air Locker
- Yukon 4.88 gears

Comment: Slightly reduced the shim size on the pinion, pattern looked good, she's driving again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Yukon PDF

[image]
[image]

[Link to PDF](https://www.yukongear.com/downloads/manuals/yukon_general_installation_instructions.pdf)

Comment: Yep, that is in the manual which came with my gears

Comment: Pinion may be too close, shim it and paint it again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fairly normal perhaps slightly high of the tooth centreline.

What are the issues that make you think you have a problem...

Comment: I've never done gears before, just looking for a second opinion 